# Lightweight parallel job scheduling engine

Tags: gratis, open-source, scheduling, clustering

I'm looking for a simple, lightweight parallel job scheduling engine, for the following workflow (in this example, from a shell):

```
$ createpool -n 2    # create a worker pool with 2 workers
$ submitjob -options # submit a job, starts immediately
$ submitjob -options # submit a job, starts immediately
$ submitjob -options # submit a job, waits for worker to become free
$ queryjob -options  # query status of a job
```

Ideally, this would enabled by a simple script or Python module that we could ship with our driver code - no separate installation needed. We only need execution on a local worker pool, no cluster applications.

The scheduler needs to allow me to create a custom initialization script, say to copy some files in place. Then it should shut the pool down once idle.

**OS**: Mac, Windows

**Price**: free, open source